# Using Spark to creating an "EventID" column to help distinguish different sets of records

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

#### My current dataset

```
+---+-----+
| ID|Event|
+---+-----+
|  1|  run|
|  1|  run|
|  1|  run|
|  1| swim|
|  1|  run|
|  1| swim|
|  1| swim|
|  1|  run|
|  1|  run|
|  1|  run|
|  1| swim|
|  1|  run|
|  1|  run|
|  2|  run|
|  2|  run|
|  2|  run|
|  2| swim|
|  2|  run|
|  2| swim|
|  2| swim|
|  2| swim|
|  2| swim|
|  2|  run|
|  3|  run|
|  3|  run|
|  3| swim|
+---+-----+
```

#### Dataset I'm after

```
+---+-----+-------+
| ID|Event|EventID|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1| swim|      1|
|  1|  run|      2|
|  1| swim|      2|
|  1| swim|      2|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1| swim|      3|
|  1|  run|      4|
|  1|  run|      4|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2| swim|      1|
|  2|  run|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2|  run|      3|
|  3|  run|      1|
|  3|  run|      1|
|  3| swim|      1|
+---+-----+-------+
```

#### My question

Does anyone mind helping me with (or referencing me) to the functions needed to create the above **EventID** column? I believe I can achieve this by applying some sort of groupby on the **ID** column and then use a lambda expression to keep track of the **Event** column pattern?

For each *unique* **ID** the rule for creating an **EventId** is that the previous **Event** record must be a "swim" and the current **Event** record must be a "run" . Note, there may be multiple 'run' and 'swim' values attached to the same **EventID**.

Any suggestions or guidance is much appreciated.

Thank you all.

#### Current code to produce the raw/example dataset

```
# My current dataset

data = [
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "run"),
       (3, "run"),
       (3, "run"),
       (3, "swim")
        ]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('ID', IntegerType(),True), \
  StructField('Event', StringType(),True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.show(30)
```

Comment: You're going to need some sort of ordering to get consistent results out of this. Getting the row numbers (or timestamps, or whatever orders the rows) will be a key part; then you can make a table which maps start times (or start rows) to specific EventIDs and do a join

Comment: Thank you @SarahMesser. I will look into it. I just updated the post with my example code.

Comment: @SarahMesser Are you saying I should create an index column to keep the data in order for each unique ID?

Comment: The trick here is to come up with a good execution strategy and then the implementation shouldn't be that bad. Here's what I'm thinking... 1) groupby `ID` 2) remove any tailing `run` from `Event` column 3) lookup `swim` locations 4) check previous row for `run`

Comment: It doesn't have to be an index column, but your description mentions an "Event" must "start" and "end".  The words "start" and "end" imply an ordering, but there's no intrinsic ordering to a dataframe or table, so you need to describe what order you have in mind.  Perhaps it's time; perhaps it's the order by which records were originally inserted into the table. It could be anything, but the order comes from your use case and I don't know what that is. Once you have a column that reflects your desired order, we can define operations where "start" and "end" are meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with line number based in spark has limitation with Spark processing as it breaks the whole parallelism and everything executes in one executor. If your data sets are huge the below solution wont work , you may have to look to have something else , The below solution is using couple of window functions and line number.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = [
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "swim"),
       (1, "run"),
       (1, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "run"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "swim"),
       (2, "run"),
       (3, "run"),
       (3, "run"),
       (3, "swim")
        ]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('ID', IntegerType(),True), \
  StructField('Event', StringType(),True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
w = Window.partitionBy('value').orderBy('index')
w1 = Window.orderBy('index')
# Assigning line number
df_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
# Assigning First Level of window function and assigning group numbers if prior row value changes using no partition window
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("valueChange",(f.col("value") != f.lag("value").over(w1)).cast("int")) \
        .fillna(0,subset=["valueChange"])\
        .withColumn("indicator",(~((f.col("valueChange") == 0))).cast("int"))\
        .withColumn("group",f.sum(f.col("indicator")).over(w1.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
# Assigning Second Level of window function and assigning group numbers with different window
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("groupvaluechnage",(f.col("group") != f.lag("group").over(w)).cast("int")) \
        .fillna(0,subset=["groupvaluechnage"])\
        .withColumn("groupindicator",(~((f.col("groupvaluechnage") == 0))).cast("int"))\
        .withColumn("secondgroup",f.sum(f.col("groupindicator")).over(w.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("GroupedNumbered")
# Selectting only needed columns
df_final=spark.sql("select value.ID,value.Event, secondgroup + 1 as EventID from GroupedNumbered order by index")
df_final.show()
```

Result produced

```
+---+-----+-------+
| ID|Event|EventID|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1|  run|      1|
|  1| swim|      1|
|  1|  run|      2|
|  1| swim|      2|
|  1| swim|      2|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1|  run|      3|
|  1| swim|      3|
|  1|  run|      4|
|  1|  run|      4|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2|  run|      1|
|  2| swim|      1|
|  2|  run|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2| swim|      2|
|  2|  run|      3|
|  3|  run|      1|
|  3|  run|      1|
|  3| swim|      1|
+---+-----+-------+
```